# connecting to oracle database on Windows

Tags: windows, oracle, networking, jdbc, ora-12170

I have two machines on my network:

1. **pc-1** is running on **Windows XP SP3**, IP `192.168.1.15`
2. **pc-2** is running on **Windows Vista**, IP `192.168.1.16`

Now I have loaded **Oracle 11gR2** on **pc-2** (Vista) and the listener is running with the following settings: `address=192.168.1.16 and port=1065.`

I am trying to connect to Oracle database via **pc-1** (XP) using `jdbc thin driver` but I get the error **The network adapter could not establish the connection.**
My `JDBC url`: jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.16:1065:ora

The **pc-2** is reachable, I checked it by `ping 192.168.1.16`

I tried a few things from **PC-1**:

- `TELNET 192.168.l.16 1065` gives error **Connecting To 192.168.1.16...Could not open connection to the host, on port 1065: Connect failed.**
       The `firewall` on **pc-2** (vista+oracle) is turned off so I don't think firewall is blocking port 1065.
- `tnsping 192.168.1.16:1065` gives **error TNS-12535: TNS:operation timed out**
- `sqlplus sys/sys@//192.168.1.16:1065/ora as sysdba` but it gives error

  > **ERROR:ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred**

Some of the commands output on `PC-2`

- `netstat -a`

`LOCAL ADDRESS`------------ `FOREIGN ADDRESS`-------------- `STATE`
192.168.1.16:1065----------------- PCNAME -------------------LISTENING

Can anyone please specify in details what shall I do? I am trying to do this first time so no idea about what is going wrong?

Comment: I think you may be facing `Issue 3:` which is given on [link](http://selvathiruppathi.blogspot.in/2012/03/network-adapter-could-not-establish.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the proper SID details in the tnsnames.ora file located under

for Linux:
/home/oracle/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora

Answer (score 0):

You don't say how you're connecting - I am assuming through TNS?

Did you specify the port of 1065 in your TNSNAMES.ORA file on the XP system?

Can you connect from your XP system using EZCONNECT?  That takes tnsnames.ora out of the equation.

```
sqlplus user/pw@//192.168.1.16:1065/db_name
```

Comment: i am doing it for first time so no idea about all this can u explain me what parameter i shall change. I also have oracle database loaded on my windows xp

Comment: So you need to modify your tnsnames.ora file to set the host, port, and sid/service names appropriately: Host=192.168.1.16, port=1065, and sid=db_name

Comment: Try this: *sqlplus sys/sys@192.168.1.16:1065/ora as sysdba*

Comment: Does `TELNET 192.168.l.16 1065` give you a black screen or a connection failure? Maybe you have a firewall running blocking port 1065.

Comment: the output is **Connecting To 192.168.1.16...Could not open connection to the host, on port 1065: Connect failed** but the firewall on windows vista pc is turned off

Comment: @DCookie       if i type **sqlplus sys/sys@192.168.1.16:1065/ora as sysdba** it gives me error **
ERROR:ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred**

Comment: Are you sure you have the right port? Try using 1521 instead of 1065.

Comment: yes, I confirm the port no. is 1065. Do i need any other utilities to connect to oracle server on Windows Vista PC

Comment: Normally what all setting a client must have before connecting to Oracle server?

Comment: On windows, if you're connecting with EZCONNECT, there are no other settings necessary.  Try putting the two slashes back in front of the IP address. It's supposed to work both ways, but... *sqlplus sys/sys@//192.168.1.16:1065/ora as sysdba*

Comment: the same error occured again ** ERROR:ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred **

Answer (score 0):

ERROR:ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred

this error usually means failure network connection

It's simple

shut down your windows firewall